# sql count by value stack by different value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have my database like this:

```
table1(article)
id | name | description | cat_id
0 | val1 |   desc1     |   1
1 | val2 |   desc2     |   2
2 | val3 |   desc3     |   1
3 | val4 |   desc4     |   2
4 | val5 |   desc5     |   1
5 | val6 |   desc6     |   2
6 | val7 |   desc7     |   0


table2(categories)
id | name 
0  | shoe
1  | glove
2  | hat
```

it should return:

```
articles_connected | categorie_name
        3          |  glove
        0          |  shoe
        3          |  hat
```

i tried:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Category.id) as article_amount, Category.name
FROM 
    article_table as Article,
    category_table as Category
WHERE
    Category.id =  Article.cat_id
```

this code just counts all as one, doesn't split up my categories. I'm not sure what goes wrong.

Comment: Please explain your required output

Comment: It should count each categories connected article ? count(category.id == article.cat_id) < as my return table says?

Comment: But for instance you have many articles with cat `hat` but in your output it says `0`

Comment: and indeed hat = 3 and shoe = 0, sorry typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT 
COUNT(Category.id) as article_amount, Category.name
FROM 
article_table as Article,
category_table as Category
WHERE
     Category.id =  Article.cat_id
group by Category.name
```

Comment: I forgot about group by.!  thanks my sql query is just fine it only needs GROUP BY Category.id and ORDER BY Category.name