# sql count by value stack by different value pt.2

Tags: mysql, sql

[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401776/sql-count-by-value-stack-by-different-value)

i have my database like this:

```
table1(article)
id | name | description | cat_id
0 | val1 |   desc1     |   1
1 | val2 |   desc2     |   2
2 | val3 |   desc3     |   1
3 | val4 |   desc4     |   2
4 | val5 |   desc5     |   1
5 | val6 |   desc6     |   2


table2(categories)
id | name 
0  | shoe
1  | glove
2  | hat
```

it should return:

```
articles_connected | categorie_name
        3          |  glove
        0          |  shoe
        3          |  hat
```

I thought this was the good solution:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Category.id) as article_amount, Category.name
FROM 
    article_table as Article,
    category_table as Category
WHERE
    Category.id =  Article.cat_id
GROUP BY
    Category.id
```

**But my code isn't correct. This SQL query doesn't count for the zero'd index
It only count the values larger than 0. how to change the following query to also count that 0'd index ?**

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(Category.id) as articles_connected, Category.name
    FROM
        arcticle as Article,
        categories as Category
    WHERE
        Category.id = arcticle .categorie       
    GROUP BY
        Category.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it right, you have no join for shoes, but want to display shoes = 0 in your result (so i ignore last column of table1 in your example).

If you join with table2, you get no match, so shoes is not in your result query.
So, in this case you could work with a left outer join:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Article.id) as articles_connected, Category.name
FROM categories as Category
left outer join arcticle as Article on  Category.id = arcticle .categorie       
GROUP BY
    Category.id
```

so you get a count for all articles, regardless if they are in table1

Comment: The query gives me a result of count = 1 on shoes while it should be 0, i've edit the criterium of the tables.. It should return 0 if the category has no articles with article.cat_id = category.id not found

Comment: Hm, that is strange, it should return 0 for shoes, if you got no cat_id 0 in table1. I tested it with some other data, and it worked. Are you sure that you have no entry with cat_id 0 in table1? Ah sorry, got the error, corrected my code

Comment: You have to count on Article.id, because this is the left joined table